# My sqlite project keeps throwing an error when adding to a table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have this code on my server, but whenever it runs, it always gives me an error. When I go to the developer console in Chrome, It just says error, but has no further information to help me figure out why. I'm making this from a template and I have gone through the changes I made over and over, but I can't figure out why it stopped working. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
// endpoint to add a dream to the database
app.post("/addDream", (request, response) => {
  console.log(`add to dreams ${request.body.name} ${request.body.price} ${request.body.email} ${request.body.description} ${request.body.photoID} ${request.body.date}`);

  // DISALLOW_WRITE is an ENV variable that gets reset for new projects
  // so they can write to the database
  if (!process.env.DISALLOW_WRITE) {
    const cleansedName = cleanseString(request.body.name);
    const cleansedPrice = cleanseString(request.body.name);
    const cleansedEmail = cleanseString(request.body.name);
    const cleansedState = cleanseString(request.body.name);
    const cleansedDescription = cleanseString(request.body.name);
    const cleansedphotoID = cleanseString(request.body.name);
    const cleansedDate = cleanseString(request.body.name);

    db.run("INSERT INTO Dreams (name, price, email, description, photoID, date) VALUES (cleansedName, cleansedPrice, cleansedEmail, cleansedState, cleansedDescription, cleansedphotoID, cleansedDate);", error => {
      if (error) {
        response.send({ message: "error!" });
        console.log("error")
      } else {
        response.send({ message: "success" });
        console.log("success")
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Here is the original code from the template that worked before I changed it:

```
// endpoint to add a dream to the database
app.post("/addDream", (request, response) => {
  console.log(`add to dreams ${request.body.dream}`);

  // DISALLOW_WRITE is an ENV variable that gets reset for new projects
  // so they can write to the database
  if (!process.env.DISALLOW_WRITE) {
    const cleansedDream = cleanseString(request.body.dream);
    db.run(`INSERT INTO Dreams (dream) VALUES (?)`, cleansedDream, error => {
      if (error) {
        response.send({ message: "error!" });
      } else {
        response.send({ message: "success" });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Here is a link to the full project if it helps: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/beta2-droneswap?path=server.js%3A215%3A0

Thank you for your time, and once again, any help is appreciated.

---

Edit: There was another error happening on startup, but I fixed that and it still doesn't work. The current error happens when I try to add a listing. I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the sql code around line 166.

Here is the current code where I think that the error is:

```
// endpoint to add a dream to the database
app.post("/addDream", (request, response) => {
  console.log(
    `add to dreams ${request.body.name}, ${request.body.price}, ${request.body.email}, ${request.body.state}, ${request.body.description}, ${request.body.photoID}, ${request.body.date}`
  );

  // DISALLOW_WRITE is an ENV variable that gets reset for new projects
  // so they can write to the database
  if (!process.env.DISALLOW_WRITE) {
    const cleansedName = cleanseString(request.body.name);
    const cleansedPrice = cleanseString(request.body.price);
    const cleansedEmail = cleanseString(request.body.email);
    const cleansedState = cleanseString(request.body.state);
    const cleansedDescription = cleanseString(request.body.description);
    const cleansedphotoID = cleanseString(request.body.photoID);
    const cleansedDate = cleanseString(request.body.date);

    db.run(
      `INSERT INTO Listings (name, price, email, state, photoID, date) VALUES (cleansedName, cleansedPrice, cleansedEmail, cleansedState, cleansedDescription, cleansedphotoID, cleansedDate)`,
      error => {
        if (error) {
          response.send({ message: "error!" });
          console.log("error");
        } else {
          response.send({ message: "success" });
          console.log("success");
        }
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: see how your doing `VALUES (?)` in the working code, repeat that with your edited code, doing `VALUES (cleansedName, ...` won't work (also note all values are set to `request.body.name`), is also unsafe to not use parameterised  queries

Comment: I changed it to that format and it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

So I remixed your example and added more content to the console logs of errors, just so I can see where the error is happening better, and it looks like your database creation is not completing successfully. I think it's because you've commented out the content inside the `db.run` call on line 165. If you don't want that code to run, you should include the `db.run` call in the comment block as well, otherwise it fails to run and that's throwing that initial error. Hope this helps!

Comment: That was definitely a problem so thanks for pointing that out, but after I changed it, it still shows the same error. Would you mind taking another look at the project and see if you can find anything else? I feel like the error might be the formatting of line 204, but I can't figure out how to change it.

Comment: Look at your app's console logs and you'll see the text matches up with line ~176. You're trying to act on rows that don't exist because you commented out the block above it that adds those rows.

Comment: I've uncommented those lines, but it still shows an error. I think it has to do with the syntax of the code around line 166, but I can't figure out what about it is wrong.